# Regression on data frame does not work in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called df with 2 variables and 71 observations. The variables are dead and duration. Now I want to do a regression with  `lm(formula = dead ~ ., data = df)`. The dependend variable is dead, but I get this error

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dead ~ ., data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     object is not a matrix

I have tried to convert the data frame to a matrix and then do the `lm()`, but then i get this error

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dead ~ ., data = df2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

```
dput(df)
structure(list(DEAD = c(26L, 229L, 43L, 21L, 19L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 
7L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 64L, 25L, 
7L, 6L, 0L, 98L, 95L, 275L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 340L, 0L, 200L, 15L, 
0L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 283L, 12L, 0L, 147L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 26L, 30L, 
0L, 34L, 0L, 557L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 99L, 1L, 78L, 18L, 49L, 3L, 3L, 
31L, 0L, 54L, 7L, 24L, 0L, 0L), DAYS = c(5, 19, 2, 15, 3, 13, 
2, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 16, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 12, 3, 20, 2, 2, 
9, 5, 13, 2, 2, 2, 4, 13, 4, 45, 28, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 
10, 7, 2, 4, 6, 4, 9, 4, 33, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 19, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
5, 9, 4, 4, 3, 2)), .Names = c("DEAD", "DAYS"), row.names = 0:70, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you post the output of dput(df)?

Comment: If you data is saved as an actual data.frame there is no reason why it shouldn't work. For example: `a <-  c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <-  c(1,2,3,4,5)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

lm(b ~., data = df)`
 Can you please output your data or provide some reproducible example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: (head(df)
  DEAD DAYS
0   26    5
1  229   19
2   43    2
3   21   15
4   19    3
5    2   13)
>  This are the first observations. Do you need more? I am quite new in R and stackoverflow, so I do not have many experience.

Comment: @EteB : Instead of `head(df)`, run `dput(df)` and post the output here

Comment: I have posted the output.

Comment: @EteB it does not work because you use `dead` instead of `DEAD`. So this should work:
`lm(formula = DEAD ~ ., data = df)`

Comment: Or just rename the variables.

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is really simple you used wrong dependent variable name `dead` instead of `DEAD` in your formula. Therefore, next time just remember to insert correct variable names and it should work just fine.

Here is your regression, with correct dependent variable name.

```
lm(formula = DEAD ~ ., data = df)
```